# React .NET Enable CORS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs

Been attempting to integrate a React front-end with a .NET Framework backend and I am constantly coming into contact with CORS errors. The request I am sending to the server works on Postman. I extracted the code from Postman and put it into my react app (Fetch) and I receive the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:33333/Token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

However, on my .NET backend I added the following filter:

```
using System;
       using System.Web.Mvc;
       
       namespace TheFifth.Cors
       {
           public class AllowCrossSiteAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
           {
               public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
               {
                   filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
   "*");
                   filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
   "*");
                   filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
   "true");
       
                   base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
               }
           }
       }
```

Then referenced the Filter at the top of my Controller

```
[AllowCrossSite]
public class DA_Object
{
  //some code
 }
```

Does anyone know why my .NET backend or my React Frontend is preventing me from communicating across different ports - even though it works on Postman?

Additional Details

```
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    
    var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
    urlencoded.append("type", "x");
    urlencoded.append("username", "x@x.com");
    urlencoded.append("password", "x@");
    
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: urlencoded,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };
    
    fetch("http://localhost:33333/api/Token", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: Your react app probably runs in a local development server thus its cross origun. The postman app is proabbly same doamin. Allow credentials is not compliant with allow origin *

Answer (score 0):

In your startup.cs
in the ConfigureServices method you should have something like this, if you don't have then add it:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(DefaultCorsPolicyName, builder =>
            {
                //App:CorsOrigins in appsettings.json can contain more than one address with splitted by comma.
                builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
```

And in your appsettings.json add http://0.0.0.0:80 like this:

```
 "App": {
...
"CorsOrigins": "http://*.mycompany.com,http://0.0.0.0:80",
...}
```

Another solution is to add a CORS extention in your browser and enable it, but it's not recommended